# Create menu for more sections

Tags: java, menu

I'm about to create a menu box which will have more sections for ex. (avatar pictures, coupons and more stuff) but i don't really know how do i can do that, i have taken a picture to show you what i'm saying ( http://prntscr.com/3dodfw ). The red marker is where i want the menu to be so when i will choose a section in the combo box the items in the menu to be changed. If somebody can explain me or show me how i can do that i will appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the red area you can add a `JPanel` with `CardLyout` and put your different "stuff" on different cards. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). To switch between the cards add an `ActionListener` or `ItemListener` to your `JComboBox`. See [Handling Events on a Combo Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners).

Comment: I'm using NetBeans and i can't do it that code by hand because i already design the program so if you can give me a tip of doing that in NetBeans with design tool ?